# Python script to extract all subdirectories according to filename

Tags: python

My directory contains several folders, each with several subdirectories of their own. I need to move all of the files that contain 'Volume.csv' into a directory called Volume.

```
Folder1
|---1Area.csv
|---1Circumf.csv
|---1Volume.csv

Folder2
|---2Area.csv
|---2Circumf.csv
|---2Volume.csv

Volume
```

I'm trying combinations of os.walk and regex to retrieve the files by filename but not having much luck.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Sunworshipper, thank you for the answer!

I ran the following code and it moved the entire directory rather than just file name containing 'Volume'. Is it clear why that happened?

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "~/Stats/"
dest_dir = "~/Stats/Volume/"

file_paths = set()

for dir_, _, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for fileName in files:
        if "Volume" in fileName:
            relDir = os.path.relpath(dir_, source_dir)
            file_paths.add(relDir)

for matched in file_paths:
    shutil.move(matched, dest_dir)
```

Comment: Ah my mistake I thought you wanted the folders that have that file.  Easy fix, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `glob` for this. It returns a list of path names matching the expression you give it.

```
import glob
import shutil

dest = 'testfiles/'

files = glob.glob('*/*test.csv')

for file in files:
    shutil.move(file, dest)
```

I used relative paths but you can also use absolute paths. 
`shutil` moves the documents to the new location. See the `glob.glob` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for more info.

Comment: Pleasure, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import shutil
```

Setup your source and destination directories

```
source_dir = "/Users/nenad/Documents/Python Files/Random Tests"
dest_dir = "/Users/nenad/Documents/Python Files/Random Tests/volume"
```

This set will now hold paths of all files matching your substring.

```
file_paths = set()
```

Now I only consider the directories that contain a file which has a substring "hello" in the filename.

```
for dir_, _, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for fileName in files:
        if "hello" in fileName:
            relDir = os.path.relpath(dir_, source_dir)
            relFile = os.path.join(relDir, fileName)
            file_paths.add(relFile)
```

And now you just move them to your destination with shutil.

```
for matched in file_paths:
    shutil.move(matched, dest_dir)
```

Sorry for the misread :)
Best regards